# Time complexity (in Θ-notation) in terms of n?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Can someone please help me with this problem? Any help would be much appreciated?

Thanks in advance!!

```
sum = 0;
for (i = n; i > 0; i = i/3)
    for (j = 0; j < n^3; j++)
        sum++;
```

What is the time complexity (in Θ–notation) in terms of n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is typically assumed that addition can be done in constant time, so each time you increment `sum`, you spend $O(1)$ time (which we'll think of as $1$ unit of time). As that is the only thing that contributes to the time complexity, you just need to figure out how many times you are incrementing `sum`.

The inner for loop doesn't depend on `i`, so let's look at that first. For each number `j` between $0$ and $n^3$, you increment the sum. How many times do you increment `sum` each time the inner for loop runs? You increment it a total of $n^3$ times.

Now let's look at the outer loop. We again want to know how many times the loop runs. The question is, how many times can you divide $n$ by $3$ before it becomes less than $1$? If you think about it, you'll see that this is very near $\log_3 n$. So the outer loop runs $\log_3 n$ times.

In total, the outer loop runs $\log_3 n$ times, and in each of those runs the inner loop runs $n^3$ times, meaning that `sum` increments about $n^3 \log_3 n$ times.

Comment: You don't need to be as specific as $\log_3$ as $\mathcal{\Theta}\left(\log_a(n)\right)$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{\Theta}\left(\log_b(n)\right)$ (this is because they only differ by a constant).

Comment: I really appreciate your help! :D

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop is independent of the outer loop variable $i$.  The inner loop *always* loops $n^3$ times.  Look at the outer loop, $i$ is initially $n$, therefore after one iteration it is $\frac{n}{3}$, then $\frac{n}{3^2}$, then $\frac{n}{3^3}$.  Assuming integer division the outer loop continues (approximately) until $\frac{n}{3^k} < 1$.  This means $k \approx \log_3\left(n\right)$.  Therefore the the run time would be $\mathcal{\Theta}\left(n^3\log\left(n\right)\right)$.